# Is it possible to debug Play! tests from IntelliJ, with a moduled that is located in a sub-folder?

Tags: java, playframework

My folder structures:

- root

  - .idea folder
  - Other Unrelated projects
  - myplayapp

    - src                        (the Actual Play! folder)
    - myplayapp.iml
    - app
    - conf
    - logs
    - public
    - ...

I'm trying to run/debug my first unit test from within IntelliJ, and getting an error "`Cannot read application.conf`". When I debug into Play.readConfiguration(), I see that Play.init() is passed a file pointing at the root folder (it's ".", but its absolute path points to `root`).

I've tried passing the argument `-Dapplication.path=myplayapp\src`, but I don't think it's even processed before the error is thrown.

Is there something I can do here? In the meantime, I'll try creating an IntelliJ project within the `myplayapp` folder, but that's a workaround, not a real solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is:

- Launch your application in test mode (with Debug config) from IntelliJ
- Put the breakpoints in your tests
- Go to http://localhost:9000/@tests and select the tests from your module
- Run the tests

That should work, barring any other unrelated issues.

Comment: So ... does the @tests route only work if I launch Play! from IntelliJ? I'm trying it now with the instance I launched from the command line, and get "route not found" on localhost:9000/@tests