# How to debug play framework 2.1.0 scala tests in intellij

Tags: playframework-2.1

i try to debug some tests with intellij.

I have configurated the remote debug as explain in : [How to make the debugging in playframework in IntelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390178/how-to-make-the-debugging-in-playframework-in-intellij-idea)

And can debug controllers and stuff. When I try to debug tests such as explain in:
[Is it possible to debug Play! tests from IntelliJ, with a moduled that is located in a sub-folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151448/is-it-possible-to-debug-play-tests-from-intellij-with-a-moduled-that-is-locate)

But i recibe the next message:

```
Action not found

For request 'GET /@tests'
These routes have been tried, in this order:
1GET/controllers.Application.index
2GET/assets/$file<.+>controllers.Assets.at(path:String = "/public", file:String)
3GET/api/crawl/task/begincontrollers.services.crawler.CrawlingService.begin
4GET/api/crawl/task/silk
```

Any idea what happen here? I'm runing the server in debug mode and run play test, only run the test in console mode. Not as server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, SBT is forking a new process to execute tests. Your IDE is connected to the SBT main process but not to the "forked" one, that's why debugging doesn't work.

You can override this by defining the following setting in your Build.scala file :

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  sbt.Keys.fork in Test := false
)
```

Now, the main process will be used to execute the tests (when executing `test` from the play console) and your IDE should be able to correctly debug them.

Comment: In Play 2.3, this is accomplished by adding `fork in Test := false` to your `build.sbt` file.

Comment: In Play 2.3 this accomplished by adding the `Keys.fork in Test := false` to your `build.sbt` file (The @cwc comment is incorrect, this may work in other versions).  See : [Play Framework Documintation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Configuration) This works in NetBeans 8.0.

Comment: @fishjd I did not intend to imply that this only works in one version, merely that I verified that it works with Play 2.3.

Comment: @cwc the line should be "Keys.fork in ..." in your comment you have "fork in ..."  and missing the "Keys.". Sorry, I wasn't very clear.   Just trying to save others time.  I do thank you for your comment.   If you fix it I'll delete my comments.

Comment: @fishjd Well, what I posted is what I have in my build.sbt, and it seems to be working.